# Private blockchain nodes not running in background

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, ubuntu, aws

Sir I am creating a private blockchain using geth.
Doing it on aws ubuntu

My geth.service file contains
Unit]
Description=Ethereum go client

```
[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
Restart=always
After=network.target
Requires=network.target
ExecStart=/usr/bin/geth --networkid 9988 --datadir /opt/ethpoa2/node1/data --port 30303 --ipcdisable --syncmode full --http --http.corsdomain "" --http.port 8545 --bootnodes "enode://a92c32b43e7d684a1b18f464c086f4992d26f4d742fdc6225e5be3b1aa02b294be233c1778e7800f3056167453f542b9be4b89f241548e1d33b18bbc0654380c@3.219.118.50:30303" --http.addr "172.31.30.236" --unlock "0x9Dc43e1cb4669f2f7eEbBbFD6D2AdAc14C008c21" --password /opt/ethpoa2/node1/password.txt --http.api personal,admin,db,eth,net,web3,miner,shh,txpool,debug,clique --ws --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.port 8546 --ws.origins "" --ws.api personal,admin,db,eth,net,web3,miner,shh,txpool,debug,clique --maxpeers 25 --miner.etherbase "0x9Dc43e1cb4669f2f7eEbBbFD6D2AdAc14C008c21" --miner.gasprice 0 --miner.gaslimit 9999999 --allow-insecure-unlock
```

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

And sir I have created the boot node [node0] now

I am creating other node.

And connecting them
But they are not running in background

please help me sir

I am making a geth.service file
And
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: You can also give other methods to run node in background in private blockchain geth aws ubuntu

Comment: Did you examine the geth log?